# Merging workbooks in a folder into a central workbook based on name and date of file

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have multiple files, always with one sheet, in a folder. I need to merge these separate files into a central workbook with multiple sheets, called the same as original workbook, based on the name and date of the original files.

For example, in a folder I may have the following files:

```
Fund1809_Equity_20140917
Fund1809_FI_20140917
Fund1809_Unlisted_20140917
Fund1809_Equity_20141221
Fund1809_FI_20141221
Fund780_Equity_20140917
Fund68092_Equity_20140917
```

I need to place all files with the same fund name and date into a workbook. Therefore, the expected result should be 4 workbooks:

1. Fund1089_20140917 with "Equity", "FI" and "Unlisted" tabs
2. Fund1089_20141221 with "Equity" and "FI" tabs
3. Fund780_20140917 with "Equity" tab
4. Fund68092_20140917 with "Equity" tab

I have code that sorts based on the first 4 characters of the fund name. Thus, I'm running into problems as the length of the fund code is not fixed to 4 and it also does not sort according to date. Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
Const TO_DELETE_SHEET_NAME As String = "toBeDeleted"
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim settingSheetsNumber As Integer
Dim settingDisplayAlerts As Boolean
Dim dict As Object
Dim wkbSource As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim filepath As String
Dim code As String * 4
Dim wkbDestination As Excel.Workbook
Dim varKey As Variant
Dim sourceFolder As String
Dim destinationFolder As String
'------------------------------------------------------------------

'Change [SheetsInNewWorkbook] setting of Excel.Application object to
'create new workbooks with a single sheet only.
With Excel.Application
    settingDisplayAlerts = .DisplayAlerts
    settingSheetsNumber = .SheetsInNewWorkbook
    .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set dict = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sourceFolder = "C:\Users\ThomasK\Desktop\Test\"
destinationFolder = "C:\Users\ThomasK\Desktop\"
filepath = Dir(sourceFolder)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While filepath <> ""

    If VBA.Right$(filepath, 5) = ".xlsx" Then

        Set wkbSource = Excel.Workbooks.Open(sourceFolder & filepath)
        Set wks = wkbSource.Worksheets(1)
        code = VBA.Left$(wkbSource.Name, 4)

        'If this code doesn't exist in the dictionary yet, add it.
        If Not dict.exists(code) Then
            Set wkbDestination = Excel.Workbooks.Add
            wkbDestination.Worksheets(1).Name = TO_DELETE_SHEET_NAME
            Call dict.Add(code, wkbDestination)
        Else
            Set wkbDestination = dict.Item(code)
        End If

        Call wks.Copy(Before:=wkbDestination.Worksheets(1))
        wkbDestination.Worksheets(1).Name = VBA.Mid$(filepath, 6)

        Call wkbSource.Close(False)

    End If

    filepath = Dir

Loop

'Save newly created files.
For Each varKey In dict.keys
    Set wkbDestination = dict.Item(varKey)

    'Remove empty sheet.
    Set wks = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = wkbDestination.Worksheets(TO_DELETE_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wks Is Nothing Then wks.Delete

    Call wkbDestination.SaveAs(Filename:=destinationFolder & varKey & ".xlsx")

    Call wkbDestination.Close(True)

Next varKey

'Restore Excel.Application settings.
With Excel.Application
    .DisplayAlerts = settingDisplayAlerts
    .SheetsInNewWorkbook = settingSheetsNumber
End With

End Sub
```

Is regex needed to identify the fund name?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to import the file names to an array, and then seperate the names on the "_" character. Then create an extra column in the array that concatenates the first and third column of the array. Here are now your filenames. Now you loop over the array and check if there is already a file of which the name is equal to the fourth column of the array. If not create it by copying the worksheet to a new book. If it is present copy the worksheet to the existing book.

Comment: Hello Luuklag, thanks for the reply. Do I import the name into a string? How do you go about separating the "_" though ?

Comment: Have a look at the Split function: http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/